# ASP.NET MVC 5 : Persist shared view radio button selection/value throughout session

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm a new developer working on a asp.net mvc app that needs to swap its data sources between a test and production instance. I created a model for a reference table in the DB. A TEST and PROD record with corresponding fields.

```
 public enum Instance
    {
        TEST,
        PROD
    }
    public class AppConfiguration
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Instance Instance { get; set; } //in db record for 0 or 1 (TEST or PROD)
        public string thisFolder { get; set; } //in db record for this folder path in TEST and PROD
        public string thatFolder { get; set; }//in db record for that folder path in TEST and PROD

        public string ManagerServer { get; set; }//in db  record for TEST server and PROD server

    }
```

then a radio button in the shared view navbar to select TEST or PROD. So in _Layout navbar html a little toggle switch/radio button:

```
           <div class="btn-group" id="envstatus" data-toggle="buttons">
                <label class="btn btn-default btn-on-2 btn-xs active">
                    <input type="radio" value="1" id="PRD" checked="checked">PRD
                </label>
                <label class="btn btn-default btn-off-2 btn-xs ">
                    <input type="radio" value="0" id="QA">QA
                </label>
            </div>
```

I'm stuck on a couple aspects here:

1. I assume I need to POST the value of the radio selection 'onchange' to some controller. How do I handle/structure this for a shared _Layout view?
2. I need to persist that selection as the user navigates the site (cookie? session?  etc)

Any guidance is much appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Cookies can be used to store/retrieve the value of the Instance property. You can use a global action filter to read/write to the cookie.

Session should be avoided as much as possible. ViewState does not work with ASP.NET MVC.